# Android Scheduled Notification with Buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

So i want to send a scheduled notificaiton to the user based on user defined delay. The problem is when when user set a specific delay lets say 10 seconds the notificaiton trigger at that time not on the schedule time,
Here is what i tried

1. Instead of directly notifiying the notification manager i add a condition and then notified the notification manager, the problem with this is that the notification gets send without the buttons

```
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() > triggerTime) {
              notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)

        }
```

```
    fun sendScheduledNotificationWithButtons(
        title: String,
        message: String,
        delayMillis: Long
    ) {
        val notificationId = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()

        val button1Text: String = "Delay"
        val button2Text: String = "Go to Task"

        // Create the pending intents for the buttons
        val delayIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        delayIntent.putExtra("Type", "Delay")
        val delayPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, delayIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val goToActivityIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        goToActivityIntent.putExtra("Type", "GoToActivity")
        val goToPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, goToActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val intent = Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("notification_id", notificationId)
        intent.putExtra("notification_message", message)
        intent.putExtra("notification_title", title)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            notificationId,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMillis

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_1024)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon_1024, button1Text, delayPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon_1024, button2Text, goToPendingIntent)
            .build()

        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

        // Schedule the notification for the future time
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
    }
```

i want to see a scheduled notificaiton with buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar class and add seconds or mins which you want to delay and get timeinmillis from calendar class.

```
val calSet: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
 calSet.add(Calendar.SECOND, triggerTime)
```

And used setExact method

```
alarmManager.setExact(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.timeInMillis, pendingIntent
                    )
```

**To schedule a notification you need to register a alarm broadcast receiver which will trigger on exact time you schedule your alarm**